# firebase is not defined in react native

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-native

I have a simple react native app. And I have firebase authentication other and firebase functions like(signIn,signUp).

It works fine in the App.js but when I try to import all firebase stuff from another file that I created "Firebase.js", it gives error. Says

> firebase is not defined

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this into your Firebase.js file

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
 const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "-",
authDomain: "",
databaseURL: "",
storageBucket: "",
messagingSenderId: "",
}
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default firebase;
```

then import firebase from 'your file path'

Comment: I have used above mentioned code but it is not working, i am getting firebase as undefined